# How to use an atom which has the result of a http-request in reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

This is what I'm using to make a remote call using the clj-http library.

```
(defn make-remote-call [endpoint]
  (go (let [response (<! (http/get endpoint
                       {:with-credentials? false}))])))
     (reset! app-state response)
    ;(js/console.log (print response)))))
```

The above print to console works fine

```
(defn call []
  (let [x (r/atom (make-remote-call site))]
   (js/console.log x)
```

this spits out `#object[cljs.core.async.impl.channels.ManyToManyChannel]` in the console.

What can I do to return the response in the `make-remote-call` function.

I used the response to set an atom's value. Trying to reference values inside the atom results in errors like `"Uncaught Error: [object Object] is not ISeqable"` and `No protocol method IDeref.-deref defined for type null:`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional info

Answer (score 1):

`make-remote-call` is returning a channel. Try interrogating this channel to see what's inside it.

This question should help:

[Why do core.async go blocks return a channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236869/why-do-core-async-go-blocks-return-a-channel)

I think you know this already, but you need to de-reference an atom i.e. get what is inside an atom, using `@`. Infomally speaking, the value you want is wrapped in two containers, so you need to get what's inside the atom, then what's inside the channel.